# When listview refreshes, it starts from row 1 (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I need help with listview in kotlin.

I have a timer function that fetches the updated listview data every 1 minutes from the server (firebase in this case). After the firebase is done fetching the data, i apply:

```
listview.adapter = CustomAdapter(applicationContext)
```

But the problem with this is that the listview refreshes and goes up to row 1 when I may be scrolling down to row 50. This is super annoying since I have about a hundred rows.

Any body has a solution to this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your problem is not with Kotlin, but with whatever UI system it manifests in (which you haven't mentioned).

Comment: If you reapply a new adapter each time you fetch data, then that's why this happen. A solution would be to analyze the data fetched, decide what's new, and insert it at the right place (using notifyDataInserted() for example)

Answer (score 0):

This is not relevant to Kotlin but how you use the Android APIs. You should not set a new adapter everytime the list is updated. You are just starting over from the beginning. I would recommend using [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html). Look at this blog for a quick example in Kotlin: https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-diffutil-kotlin/